# Phrase that roughly means "I'm fine with it"

Tags: phrase-request

There's some phrase in English that roughly means "I'm fine with it". I thought that phrase is "is it" (or "it is"), as in:

> — I want strawberry ice cream
>
> — Strawberry ice cream is it

But then I didn't find it in a dictionary

Please remind me of that phrase (I hope I'm hallucinating, and that such a phrase actually exists)

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're thinking of "it is," used as a tag when deciding among multiple options. In that case, this proposed duplicate should help: [Meaning of "it is" at the end of sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22270/meaning-of-it-is-at-the-end-of-sentence)

Comment: There's also an English Language and Usage question on [X it is](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508107/is-saying-x-it-is-too-informal-a-response-for-a-casual-workplace-environment).

Comment: "is it" would be a question. Strawbery ice cream is it?

Comment: Note: this doesn't really mean "I'm fine with it, I lend it my vote," so much as "the matter is decided and this is the choice." It could even be a choice you *weren't* fine with!

Comment: The construction *"Strawberry ice cream **is it**"* isn't right for the context. The ice-cream seller would say *"Strawberry ice cream **it is**"* - effectively meaning *"You can indeed have what you asked for".* If the seller had instead offered plain vanilla ice-cream, and that alternative was perfectly acceptable to the buyer, the buyer could convey that with *"Vanilla **suits me**".*

Comment: The barman in a pub might ask, for example, *"The usual, **is it**?"* when one of his regular customers comes in. That means *"Do you want your usual drink?"*

Comment: Note that *"Vanilla **suits me**"* strongly implies that the speaker is *perfectly* happy with what's being offered. The alternative *"Vanilla **will do**"* means the speaker will *accept* vanilla, but it strongly implies that wouldn't be his *first* choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you want to go to the movies or to the concert?
>
> -- The concert.
>
> Then concert it is!

It means "OK, as you wish."

The tone can be informal and jaunty if the speaker is happy to oblige. But it can be just the opposite:

> Guide:  Taking the eastern tributary is a bad idea. There are dangerous rapids 100 miles upriver.
>
> Linguist:  But the eastern route will spare us three days journey. And I'm eager to record the language of the tribes living in that region.
>
> Guide: Eastern tributary it is, then. But you may regret the decision.

Answer (score 1):

### A common phrase with "It Is" in it

If your looking for a common phrase with "It is" that means you have accepted something, but are only fine with it, maybe it's this.

"It is what it is"

### Using "It Is" by itself

If you say "It is" by itself, it could mean you are fine, but only as a confirmation to a question, or agreeing with what someone said.

Confirming a question
Person 1: "Is strawberry ice cream okay?"
Person 2: "It is"

Agreeing with someone
Person 1: "Strawberry ice cream is good."
Person 2: "It is"

### Meaning of "Strawberry ice cream is it"

Saying "Strawberry ice cream, is it?" is like asking the question, "Is that strawberry ice cream?". It's possible to speak a question like this with a grumpy tone, so it sounds like a rhetorical question, and you are only asking, because you didn't like what they said.

### Meaning of "Strawberry ice cream it is"

The meaning of "Strawberry ice cream it is" changes a lot based on how you say it.

"Strawberry ice cream, it is!" with a happy tone, sounds like it's going to happen, and your happy about it.

"Strawberry ice cream it is." with a neutral tone, sounds like it's going to happen, and your fine with it.

"Strawberry ice cream it is." with an unhappy tone, sounds like it's going to happen, and your not not happy about it.

There are probably more ways you can say it to convey different meanings.

### Ways to say your fine with strawberry ice cream

There are a lot of different sentences you can also use to say your fine with strawberry ice cream:

1. "Strawberry ice cream works for me."
2. "I'm okay with strawberry ice
   cream."
3. "Strawberry ice cream's alright."
4. "I can go with strawberry
   ice cream."
5. "Strawberry ice cream is okay."
6. "Strawberry ice cream
   will do."
7. "Strawberry ice cream? Sure, that's fine."